# How do I either uninstall Ubuntu or get my wireless internet to work

Tags: installation, boot, wireless, networking, uninstall

I'm sorry its a vague question but i'm stuck with 2 options:

- a) uninstall ubuntu and reload Windows XP onto my laptop (which I would rather not do as I really like Ubuntu - despite how unused to I am with it) or
- b) somehow get my wireless internet to work.

With A, I kinda know what to do: boot the CD from the BIOS menu and load from there (I have installed new OS' a couple times before). The only problem is I have 2 options when I reboot my PC: `F9= boot device menu; F10= ROM based setup`.  <kbd>F9</kbd> does nothing but take me to another menu where my only 2 options both take me to the GNU GRUB screen- where my normal boot takes me anyway.   And <kbd>F10</kbd> takes me to a menu that says `Setup Password`, which has not been set up and I cant find any evidence of a factory/default password. I have 3 attempts and I have no clue what to do about that.

Now with B, when my laptop ran XP the wireless worked perfectly. Now the only way I get internet is in my living room - which is MASSIVELY inconvenient for me seeing as my room is outside. I have downloaded the driver from 'Additional Drivers', reset my computer (with difficulty, it also doesn't seem to like turning off, so I have to 'kill' it) and still nothing! I have looked all over the internet trying to find solutions but I just cant seem to get it to work. I also have a USB wireless stick but I can't load the driver from the CD.

I am VERY new to Linux, not very technical and in need of help!
-Running Ubuntu 12.04 32bit on a HP Compaq nx6325 Notebook

Thank you to anyone who replies, its much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. These are really two questions. Please post them separately. You can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/371307/edit) this question. Also please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/371307/edit) your question and plug your USB wireless stick, open a terminal with Ctrl + Alt + t and copy & paste what the commands `lspci` and `lsusb` give you.

Answer (score 0):

Using either Snaptic Package Manager or Ubuntu's own Software Centre, remove "bcmwl-kernel-source" if it's already installed.

Next, search for "firmware-b43-installer” and “b43-fwcutter” and install both.

Finally, running Software Sources and checking the Additional Drivers tab you should find Broadcom STA Wireless Driver that you can select, install and on reboot hopefully have wireless working ok...

Comment: Right, so I tried to find/remove "bcmwl-kernel-source" but couldn't find anything.  I managed to install both "firmware-b43-installer” and “b43-fwcutter” using terminal, after finding out how it worked. And lastly, I couldn't figure out how to find 'Broadcom STA Wireless Driver' - still no more additional drivers. And my wireless is still not working.  My laptop has a button that turns wifi on and off and since I put Ubuntu on it, it hasn't worked.  And also, my computer still doesn't seem to restart properly - it just gets stuck on the ubuntu loading screen. Thanks a bunch for replying